# Concurrent async requests - keep track of necessary timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, nominatim

With Nominatim requests I need to keep a timeout of 1500ms between every requests. How do I handle that if multiple concurrent running processes keep firing on that function?

Code:

osmService:

```
export const getLocation = async (zipCode, street) => {
  if (!zipCode) {
    return {
      address: null,
      cacheHit: false,
    };
  }

  const cacheData = await getAddress(zipCode, street);

  if (cacheData && cacheData.length === 1) {
    return { address: cacheData[0].address, cacheHit: true };
  } if (cacheData && cacheData.length > 1) {
    logger.error('Found multiple address, this should not be', zipCode + street);
  }


  try {
    const responseObj = await getNominatimLocation(zipCode, street);
    if (responseObj) {
      const returnObj = {
        ...responseObj.address,
        lat: responseObj.lat,
        lon: responseObj.lon,
        displayName: responseObj.display_name,
      };
      await insertAddress(zipCode, street, null, returnObj);
      return {
        address: returnObj,
        cacheHit: false,
      };
    }
    return {
      address: null,
      cacheHit: false,
    };
  } catch (ex) {
    logger.error(`Error getting location from ${zipCode} ${street}`, ex);
  }
  return {
    address: null,
    cacheHit: false,
  };
};
```

As you can see I have a caching layer in between. So when the request was hit by cache I do not need to wait 1500ms.

```
export const getNominatimLocation = async (zipCode, street, query, retries = 0) => {
  if (retries > 5) {
    return null;
  }
  try {
    const qs = {
      format: 'json',
      q: query,
      postalcode: zipCode,
      addressdetails: 1,
      country: 'Deutschland',
      street,
      'accept-language': 'de',
    };
    const response = await requestPromise()
      .get({
        url: OSM_SEARCH,
        qs,
        timeout: 12000,
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'xxxxxxx',
        },
      });
    return JSON.parse(response)[0];
  } catch (ex) {
    logger.info(`Nominatim timed out - retry ${retries}`, ex);
    await timeout(9000);
    return await getNominatimLocation(zipCode, street, query, retries + 1);
  }
};
```

Since Nominatim often times out I need to do this recursive call (does not need to be recursive - was just easier).

Now let's suppose I have following jobs (backend engine) that want to get locations

```
const jobA = asnyc () => {
  const {address, cacheHit} = await getLocation(10243);
  if(!cacheHit){
    await timeout(1500)
  }
}

const jobB = asnyc () => {
  const {address, cacheHit} = await getLocation(10245);
  if(!cacheHit){
    await timeout(1500)
  }
}

const startJobs = async () => {
 Promise.all([jobA(),jobB()])
 console.log('all jobs done');
}
```

The jobs partially represent my current code structure. In my code the jobs do more (call other services etc.).

Now when I have this layout - how can I make sure to keep 1500ms between every Nominatim call when there is no cacheHit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a lock that only unlocks every 1.5 seconds:

```
 let lock = Promise.resolve();
 let aquireLock = () => (lock = lock.then(() => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1500))));
```

Then

```
await aquireLock();
// will only run every 1.5 seconds
```

Comment: But if the two requests come simultaneously (not exactly but with ms delay) then request one and two will wait 1500ms and both fire at the same time. The timeout function (sorry I did not put in code) is quite exactly like this one :)

Comment: No, they won't.

Comment: Have a look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-einstein-chu2h. Both get fired at the same time - just after 1500ms

Comment: Cool. THat your code does not work does not mean that mine does not work.

Comment: Haha - ofc not :) Would be great if you can show me how it works there